# Extract movie title from video name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match a YouTube video name to a movie, if the video corresponds to a trailer or similar.

Here are some examples

> The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part 2 Official Trailer – “We March Together”
>
> Iron Man - Trailer [HD]
>
> Disney's Frozen Official Trailer
>
> Star Wars: The Force Awakens Trailer (Official)
>
> The Martian | Teaser Trailer [HD] | 20th Century FOX

As you see, there is a lot of cruft, like the words "official", "trailer", "HD", "teaser", the publishing company like "Disney" or "20th Century Fox", and other words that are not part of the movie name. Sometimes it contains quotes or a trailer name, as is the case in Hunger Games.

Apart from the naive solution of removing all of the common words and companies, what other approach can I take?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the movie name in your code, you could just check if the video title contains the movie name. If you only want to remove special words from that string, you won't get around doing that specifically.

Comment: I want it to match any movie (that exists in IMDB). Searching for "The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part 2 Official Trailer – “We March Together"" in IMDB does not match The Hunger Games: Mockingjay Part 2

Comment: Mhh, that's a tough one, I don't think I have a solution for that. Maybe you could load all IMDB film titles and check your video title string for all of these titles. I guess that's really slow though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you want to do this using only JavaScript? Considering the amount of movie titles available you are better off employing a database and serverside code (including JavaScript on the server) as they are meant to parse through large datasets much faster than JavaScript alone. I would recommend thinking more about the architecture for this problem.

In lieu of this, using The Movie Database's API to search for movies may be simpler than trying to build your own parser. You can read the documentation for the search by movie here: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/search/searchmovie

Comment: It's a Chrome Extension. Making it talk to a server that I'd have to maintain is not ideal for my situation, but may prove necessary...

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and adding those details? Actually, as much detail about the final/desired end result would be helpful so we're able to be on target is better.